# Sending object from mongodb query, find().toArray() not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Sorry for the title, but basically I'm trying to get all the documents from a collection called "question". This is what the route looks like:

```
    app.get('/api/question', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

    var db = req.db;

    var collection = db.get('question');

    collection.find().toArray(function (err, results) {

            res.json(results);
    });

});
```

However, nothing is sent by the server, the res.json(results) never occurs. I've tested it by just sending a string and that didn't work either. Is there something wrong with my callback? Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm still very new to node and I can't seem to find an answer on stack overflow with the way that I word it. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are there any errors in console? 2. Can you try adding res.json("bla") in the end (outside of toArray callback)? That is to clarify your api/question function is being executed at all.   The use of `collection.find().toArray(callback)` is valid by itself.

Comment: Unless you have some custom wrapper in here the syntax actually looks like you are using "monk" rather than the raw node native driver. Monk "automagically" converts the "cursor" result as an array or stream to be precise. Generally speaking this should error if something is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer!